# C++ is it possible to overload the unary minus operator of an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference, unary-operator

is it possible to discern between these two methods?
should one not mutate an rvalue when in this case seems perfectly reusable?

```
TYPE a;
TYPE b = -a;      // unary operator- of a TYPE& aka lvalue ref
TYPE c = -(a+b);  // unary operator- of a TYPE&& aka rvalue ref
```

Comment: `a` and `a+b` are *lvalue* and *prvalue*  (if TYPE is builtin or its `operator+` returns by value); they aren't references

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [reference qualifier-s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) (or ref-qualifiers as in standard)

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40905649dc0c14e7

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class X
{
   public:
      int n;
      X(const X&) = default;
      X() : n(0) {}
      X(int n) : n(n) {}

      X operator- () const &  // lvalue ref-qualifier
      {
         std::cout << "&\n";
         X x(-n);
         return x;
      }

      X operator- () const && // rvalue ref-qualifier
      {
         std::cout << "&&\n";
         X x(-n);
         return x;
      }    

      friend X operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) {
          return X(lhs.n + rhs.n);
      }
};

int main()
{
    X a;
    X b = -a;      // unary operator- of a TYPE& aka lvalue ref
    X c = -(a+b);
}
```

outputs:

```
&
&&
```

Answer (score 12):

Something like:

```
class Type
{
public:
    Type& operator -() && { std::cout << "rvalue\n";  return *this; }
    Type& operator -() & { std::cout << "lvalue\n";  return *this; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89c4a487557369d7)